# TSQL, Get top N unique rows across ordered groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table of values, sorted by arbitrary segment id specified by the user.  ( I know how to do that query and below are the results )

```
SegmentID   SequenceID
3           100
3           200
3           400
3           430
1           100
1           200
1           300
1           410
2           100
2           200
2           300
2           420
```

I need a SQL query ( Sql Server 2012 ) that returns top N Records in order of Precedence where SequenceID is not repeated.

Example:  user wants 7 sequences in order of segment preference: 3, 1,2.

The correct answer is

```
   SegmentID    SequenceID
    3           100
    3           200
    3           400
    3           430
    1           300
    1           410
    2           420
```

in a nutshell, i need to traverse recordset from top to bottom, grab unique sequences as i go and add to the list.

How can I do that in a TSql statement?

Comment: You did not provide `order by` column in first result set

Comment: Is there an inherent order in the first column (date, primary key)?

Comment: You must need to have order by clause to get '1 300' instead of '2 300' what is that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #data (SegmentID int,SequenceID int);

insert into #data values
(3,100),
(3,200),
(3,400),
(3,430),
(1,100),
(1,200),
(1,300),
(1,410),
(2,100),
(2,200),
(2,300),
(2,420);
```

This table declares the ordering preference:

```
create table #prefs (Preference int, SegmentID int);
insert into #prefs values(1,3),(2,1),(3,2);

with cte as
(   
    select #data.SegmentID,
        #data.SequenceID,
        Preference,
        row_number() over (partition by SequenceID order by Preference) rn
    from #data 
    inner join #prefs on #data.SegmentID = #prefs.SegmentID
)
select SegmentId,
    SequenceID
from cte
where rn = 1
order by Preference, SequenceID;
```

Comment: Works for me :P http://rextester.com/YWV36620  good thoughts  just need a top 7 ( or x or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: 
http://rextester.com/JKNKD15000

```
With cte (SegmentID, SequenceID) as 
(SELECT 3,           100 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,           200 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,           400 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,           430 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,           100 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,           200 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,           300 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,           410 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           100 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           200 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           300 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           420),
userOrder (SegmentID, orderID) as (
 SELECT 3, 1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 3),
Results  (SegmentID, SequenceID, RN, orderID) as ( 
    Select A.*
         , Row_number() over (Partition by A.SequenceID order by B.orderID)  RN
         , B.orderID
from cte A
INNER JOIN userOrder B
  on A.SegmentID = B.SegmentID)

Select Top 7 * 
from results where RN = 1
order by OrderID, SequenceID
```

Comment: What's hardcoded? top 7?  that can be variable.  the 3,1,2 order? how else would we know what user order to apply?  that cte userOrder could simply be setup as inserts into a table (temporary or not) nothing here imo is a required hardcoded value.